# UIImageView doesn't position properly on iPad (always on 0, 0)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uiimageview

Today I faced a strange problem. I have an application which is the same for iPhone and iPad, it's an universal app, however I made two main view controllers, one for iPhone and one for iPad. I made the iPhone version first... then I copied some of the code to the iPad version. Everything seems to work fine except my logo UIImageView. I have a logo which slides down from off screen to the center of navigation bar. Before the animation I set up the UIImageView to be off screen, so then it could slide down. But, even if I put any random value in the x and y of uiimageview frame, it is still at 0, 0. It's the same code I have on iPhone and it's working ok.

Here is my initialization.

```
    UIImage *logoText = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logotext.png"];
    [logoTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    logoTextView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    // I already tried [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake......];
    logoTextView.frame = CGRectMake(389, -100, logoText.size.width, logoText.size.height);
    logoTextView.image = logoText;
    logoTextView.center = CGPointMake(389, -100);
    logoTextView.alpha = 1;
    [logoTextView addGestureRecognizer:resetGesture];
   // [logoTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view insertSubview:logoTextView atIndex:10];
```

This should actually position the UIImageView in the center and 100px off the screen. But nothing happens. It is still 0, 0. I tried it all ways I know, nothing really works...

Does somebody know, what to do? It would really help me. :)

**EDIT**

I have just found the solution... I don't know why but this only works if its in a new method... weird.

```
- (void)logoShow {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *resetGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resetValues)];

    UIImage *logoText = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logotext@2x.png"];
    logoTextView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(389, -50, logoText.size.width/1.35, logoText.size.height/1.35)];
    logoTextView.center = CGPointMake(389, -50);
    logoTextView.image = logoText;
    logoTextView.alpha = 1;
    [logoTextView addGestureRecognizer:resetGesture];
    [self.view insertSubview:logoTextView atIndex:15];


    // LOGO TEXT ANIMATION
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Logo Text Animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:4.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    logoTextView.alpha = 1;
    logoTextView.center = CGPointMake(389, 22);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [logoTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution, but `-initWithFrame:` is the designated initializer for `UIView` and subclasses, not `init`.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that. Doesn't work either :/

Comment: Well I said it wasn't a solution, but it's good practice I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the logo view as the title view of my view controller. In your -initWithNib (or similar) do this:

```
logoTextView.alpha = 0.0f ;
self.navigationItem.titleView = logoTextView ;
```

Then in your `-viewDidAppear:` method do this:

```
CALayer * layer = logoTextView.layer ;
{
    CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform" ] ;
    anim.fromValue = [ NSValue valueWithCATransfom3D:
                         CATransform3DMakeTranslate( 0, -100.0f, 0 ) ] ;
    [ layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;
}
logoTextView.alpha = 1.0f ;
```

Good luck

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, but it's giving me an error which says that there is no known class method for "valueWithCATransform3D"... :/
And actually I would like to start the logo off screen and then slide it onto the navigation bar :)

Comment: I think the code I gave you will animate from offscreen... Try it and see if it works